# How do I get this number with b4s?

Tags: python

How do I get the 30,475,543 with beautifulsoup?

```html
<span class="g47SY ">30,475,543</span>
```

I tried 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(bot.driver.page_source, "lxml")
n = soup.find('span', {'class': 'g47SY'})`

and got the result as :

`<span class=""g47SY"">30,475,872</span>`

So I tried something like

`n = soup.find('span', {'class': 'g47SY'}).text`

but that does not exists (anymore?)
Edit: My Import is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Edit:

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(bot.driver.page_source, "lxml")
        nposts = soup.find('span', {'class': 'g47SY'})
```

So I dont think I

Any help?

Comment: `soup.find('span', {'class': 'g47SY'}).text` works for me. But you also have maybe `.get_text()` available?

Comment: Nah, it says : Unresolved attribute reference 'text' for class 'PageElement'. Only __getattribute__() but this isnt what we are looking for I guess.

Comment: Things that I can do with "." is: .append, .extract .next .insert suff like this, can u do this too?

Comment: Do you mean `.extend` instead of `.extract`? Then it seems that you have a list object instead of a soup object. So I guess that you have overwritten your soup variable anywhere. If not, it is hard to tell. Please provide more context (relevant code) in your question.

Comment: See the edit please @colidyre But even íf I isolate the both lines I cant put .text

Comment: FWIW: You can improve your question following https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work

```
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
            msg_body = """\
            <html>
              <body>
                <span class="g47SY ">30,475,543</span>
              </body>
            </html>
            """
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(msg_body, "lxml")
            n = soup.find('span', {'class': 'g47SY'}).text
            print(n)
```

result is 30,475,543
i tried this and it giving the accurate results there are some installions issue from your end update to latest version of beautiful soup

Comment: I am sorry but it didnt fixed it. I got the same problem as before.

Comment: can you send me the link of page you scraping

Comment: how is it possible if a logic worked and then failed

Comment: please send me the exact error because i am getting the accurate results either you are not giving the proper class name or missing something else

Answer (score 0):

Try this if there is only one span:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(bot.driver.page_source, "lxml")
n = soup.find('span')
print(n)
```

Comment: There a lot of span. So  I dont think this could be the fix, but thanks

Comment: If there are a lot of span, you can use Xpath.  You can get references from here (https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/)

Comment: No, does not work it retuns None, even if the xpath is correct tried it with n =  n = soup.find('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as simple as shameful, it was just a problem with PyCharm and the code works even with the error

Comment: Then please mark your answer as accepted. It will help others to not spend any more unnecessary efforts into your problem.

Comment: Possible in 2 days @colidyre